# Values get changed when numpy int32 array is converted to float32

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm changing the type of numpy array `data_np` from int32 to float32 by `data_np.dtype = np.float32`
But it's changing the values from
[image]

to
[image]

and also adding an additoinal `0` column in between.
Any sugggestion on how to properly do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ndarray.dtype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dtype.html) is not meant to modify the dtype. I would use [`astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

```
data_np = data_np.astype(np.float32)
```

**Example**:

```
data_np = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,3),dtype=np.int32)
>>> data_np
array([[7, 8, 4],
       [7, 6, 8],
       [4, 5, 9]], dtype=int32)

data_np = data_np.astype(np.float32)
>>> data_np
array([[7., 8., 4.],
       [7., 6., 8.],
       [4., 5., 9.]], dtype=float32)
```